# Symfony 3 SwiftMailer as a Service

Tags: symfony-3.3

What am I missing?

services.yml

```
AppBundle\Services\ItemAddService:
   arguments: ['@mailer']
```

ItemAddService class

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;

class ItemAddService{

private $mymailer;

public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer){

    $this->mymailer = $mailer;

}

public function itemCreatedMailer(){

    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
        ->setFrom('xxx@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('xxx@gmail.com')
        ->setBody("Successfully got SwiftMailer to mail from Symfony3");

    $this->mymailer->send($message);

    return "Check mail";

}
}
```

When I call itemCreateMailer() in the controller I get this

"Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Services\ItemAddService::__construct() must be an instance of SwiftMailer, none given, called in /home/admin-daniel/symfony-test-sites/july132017/src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php"

Missing something....

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a use because you're using "\" before the class name that's mean the full class name . Have a Look to my services file https://github.com/ismail1432/eniams-website/blob/master/app/config/services.yml . After that in your Controller call the service via the id which is app.send_mail but you name it as you want . So in the Controller do that $this->get('app_send_mail')->itemCreatedMailer();

Comment: Okay. That kinda works. Now I get this...

Type error: Argument 1 passed to Swift_Mailer::newInstance() must implement interface Swift_Transport, none given, called in /home/admin-daniel/symfony-test-sites/july132017/src/AppBundle/Services/ItemAddService.php on line 20

I do not understand why the original does not work. It works in every other instance I can find "Swift_Mailer" in the docs...I appreciate your time...This framework is exhaustively convoluted...

How do I implement the Transport?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, now what's wrong ? :-)

Comment: Okay, as the error states, that I am not implementing an interface for Swift_Transport. All parameters and settings for swift seem to be correctly defined in my config and parameters files for un, pw, and transport as gmail...if I use this same message setup in an controller it works without a hitch....I don't know...

Comment: Hey, I appreciate your time. I just took out the Instance and ran with a direct call and it worked. This may not be correct but I really do appreciate you help me understand service names. That was one of my next adventures and you pretty much cleared that up. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries :-) Symfony seems very difficult at the beginning but it's not !. If helped you don't forget the vote my friend.

Answer (score -2):

Try this in services.yml

`AppBundle\Services\ItemAddService:
       arguments: 
           $mailer: '@mailer'`

Comment: I did...and I just copy pasted your code and it still doesn't work. At first I was thinking I needed a use statement for Swift but it doesn't need one as being passed an argument. I don't get it. I admit I am new to Symfony but I have a very clear understanding of PHP and feel I am missing something small...as that usually turns out to be the case...I do appreciate the response sir...